# Trim/subtract CGPath from CGPath?

Tags: ios, core-animation, subtraction, cgpath, cashapelayer

I have some `CGPath` (a poly with two circle) carried out on a `CAShapeLayer`.

**Can I trim/subtract paths like this?**

[image]

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: You can but it's pretty hard.

Comment: Thanks :) I can do it with by adding layer mask as a fallback, but I wanted to supress rasterization passes, would prefer math.

Comment: Thanks there. It was made during design process, but was a perfect fit for this question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of do the math, the result can be achieved at drawing time using `kCGBlendModeClear`.

```
// Create the poly.
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint       (context, a_.x, a_.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint    (context, b_.x, b_.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint    (context, c_.x, c_.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint    (context, d_.x, d_.y);
CGContextClosePath(context);

// Draw with the desired color.
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.color.CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);

// Create a circle.
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, (CGRect){
    b_.x - self.radius,
    b_.y - self.radius,
    self.radius * 2.0,
    self.radius * 2.0 });
CGContextClosePath(context);

// Draw with Clear (!) blend mode.
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.color.CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Geri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366183/4691224), using **Swift 5**

```swift
context.addPath(path1) // your original CGPath
context.setFillColor(color1) // your color
context.fillPath()
        
context.addPath(path2) // your clearing CGPath
context.setBlendMode(.clear) // draw with clear mode
context.fillPath()
```